# Check if object exists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, variables, null, undefined

How do I verify the existence of an object in JavaScript?

The following works:

```
if (!null)
   alert("GOT HERE");
```

But this throws an Error:

```
if (!maybeObject)
   alert("GOT HERE");
```

**The Error:**

> `maybeObject` is not defined.

Comment: The problem with this question is the use of the word 'exists'. What does 'exists' actually mean? An object can 'exist' but intentionally have no value (`let myobj = null`). In this case, accessing a property of the object causes a runtime error, which is what you're really interested in. So, while the accepted answer is technically correct and has a vast number of points, it's not of any practical value.

Answer (score 697, accepted):

You can safely use the `typeof` operator on undefined variables.

If it has been assigned any value, including null, typeof will return something other than undefined. typeof always returns a string.

Therefore

```
if (typeof maybeObject != "undefined") {
   alert("GOT THERE");
}
```

Comment: if its always a string, you really could(should) do `!==` for the comparison.

Comment: Since this is a core Javascript feature, it is a shame that there is not a better and less error-prone built-in. The string comparison prevents the compiler from 100% reliably tell us when we made a small mistake (like a typo) in these kinds of checks.

Comment: in my case, im looking to SEARCH for this object, so this doesnt help.  i want a solution i can use in console as wel, to see if object is in domtree somewhere without any clickery..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Those examples don't seem to be accessible anymore.

Comment: @StefanvandenAkker: The link to the bad example should be http://jsbin.com/ibeho3/1/. The good example was fine: http://jsbin.com/ibeho3/2/. (Sadly JSBin redirects to the latest, and people have been editing that to within an inch of its life.)

Comment: Curious as to why this was marked as the answer and has so many votes. I use some code suggested by @gblazex i.e. a method called existy which has the 1-line body `foo != null` . See the spec ES5 spec, clauses 11.9.3.2-3 https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: +onefootswill note that this answer is from 2010. Also, it's one line. Additionally, null is not the same as being undefined

Comment: @Micah just because `typeof` always returns a string, we're safe to use the simple *Not Equal* comparison operator and not *Strict Not Equal* comparison operator. There is no point using the strtict one because in this case we'll always deal with a string value. Simple *Not Equal* operator `!=` or simple *Equal* operator `==` are not always bad; there are use cases these can come to be really handy.

Answer (score 50):

There are a lot of half-truths here, so I thought I make some things clearer.

Actually you can't accurately tell if a variable exists (unless you want to wrap every second line into a try-catch block).

The reason is Javascript has this notorious value of `undefined` which strikingly doesn't mean that the variable is not defined, or that it doesn't exist `undefined !== not defined`

```
var a;
alert(typeof a); // undefined (declared without a value)
alert(typeof b); // undefined (not declared)
```

So both a variable that exists and another one that doesn't can report you the `undefined`  type.

As for @Kevin's misconception, `null == undefined`. It is due to type coercion, and it's the main reason why Crockford keeps telling everyone who is unsure of this kind of thing to always use strict equality operator `===` to test for possibly falsy values. `null !== undefined` gives you what you might expect. Please also note, that `foo != null` can be an effective way to check if a variable is neither `undefined` nor `null`. Of course you can be explicit, because it may help readability.

If you restrict the question to check if an object exists, `typeof o == "object"` may be a good idea, except if you don't consider arrays objects, as this will also reported to be the type of `object` which may leave you a bit confused. Not to mention that `typeof null` will also give you `object` which is simply wrong.

The primal area where you really should be careful about `typeof`, `undefined`, `null`, `unknown` and other misteries are host objects. They can't be trusted. They are free to do almost any dirty thing they want. So be careful with them, check for functionality if you can, because it's the only secure way to use a feature that may not even exist.

Comment: Simply doing `foo!=null` will produce a ReferenceError if `foo` is not defined. Thus, it's better to use `typeof`, unless you're planning on catching the exception.

Comment: I write it down for you again: *`undefined !== not defined` && `foo != null can be an effective way to check if a variable is neither 'undefined' nor 'null'`*. I didn't say `!= null` is good for checking if it exists. You're taking it out of context. (I also mentioned that it's a sidenote, not strictly related to the subject of the OP's question)

Comment: You again confuse the term not defined with the type `undefined`. They are not the same. `(note) it can be used !== you should use`. Use common sense while reading. When the variable is declared (parameter list, or elsewhere) and you wanna check whether it's got a value, `!=` null is completely safe. It's a different usecase than what the OP asked for, that's why I intruduced it as a note. The whole paragraph is about @Kevin's post and type coercion btw. As you can notice if you read carefully.

Comment: @JAL you're missing the part that you are *not* risking an error using `!= null` when you know that the variable has been declared. This is very useful for checking function arguments, consider: `var hasValue = function(foo) {return foo != null}`

Comment: @tybro0103 that's true, but the entire issue is "How do I verify the existence of an object in JavaScript?". If you are certain it's been declared, that is a different situation.

Comment: I know it was stated in the answer, but I want to reiterate that "undefined" does not exactly mean "not defined." The snippet `foo != null` as a check amounts to `(foo !== null && foo !== undefined)`, which will throw an exception if the variable has not been defined.

Answer (score 19):

You can use:

```
if (typeof objectName == 'object') {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Two ways:

### typeof for local variables

You can test for a local object using typeof:

```
if (typeof object !== "undefined") {}
```

### window for global variables

You can test for a global object (one defined on the global scope) by inspecting the window object:

```
if (window.FormData) {}
```

Answer (score 9):

If that's a global object, you can use `if (!window.maybeObject)`

Comment: I found `window.hasOwnProperty('maybeObject')` is a little more readable, if it's a global object

Answer (score 8):

If you care about its existence only ( has it been declared ? ), the approved answer is enough :

```
if (typeof maybeObject != "undefined") {
   alert("GOT THERE");
}
```

If you care about it having an actual value, you should add:

```
if (typeof maybeObject != "undefined" && maybeObject != null ) {
   alert("GOT THERE");
}
```

As `typeof( null ) == "object"`

e.g. `bar = { x: 1, y: 2, z: null}`

```
typeof( bar.z ) == "object" 
typeof( bar.not_present ) == "undefined"
```

this way you check that it's neither `null` or `undefined`, and since `typeof` does not error if value does not exist plus `&&` short circuits, you will never get a run-time error.

Personally, I'd suggest adding a helper fn somewhere (and let's not trust `typeof()` ):

```
function exists(data){
   data !== null && data !== undefined
}

if( exists( maybeObject ) ){
    alert("Got here!"); 
}
```

Comment: The first one already accomplishes the second. If it doesnt have a value it doesnt consider it to exist.

Comment: @TS: not so; `typeof null` is `object`, as this answer says, for historical reasons. If you don't add the second test, you'll get a runtime error.

Answer (score 6):

You could use "typeof".

```
if(typeof maybeObject != "undefined")
    alert("GOT HERE");
```

Answer (score 5):

I used to just do a `if(maybeObject)` as the null check in my javascripts.

```
if(maybeObject){
    alert("GOT HERE");
}
```

So only if `maybeObject` - is an object, the alert would be shown.
I have an example in my site.

https://sites.google.com/site/javaerrorsandsolutions/home/javascript-dynamic-checkboxes

Comment: The problem is if **maybeObject** was not declared it will throw the Error:

**maybeObject is not defined**

Comment: if `maybeObject` is `0, 0.0, or ""` , it checks to false

Answer (score 5):

The thread was opened quite some time ago. I think in the meanwhile the usage of a ternary operator is the simplest option:

```
maybeObject ? console.log(maybeObject.id) : ""
```

Comment: Yea, something along the lines of `var maybeObject = typeof maybeObject !== "undefined" ? Chart:false;` and check if not `false`.

Answer (score 4):

I've just tested the `typeOf` examples from above and none worked for me, so instead I've used this:

```js
    btnAdd = document.getElementById("elementNotLoadedYet");
    if (btnAdd) {
       btnAdd.textContent = "Some text here";
    } else {
      alert("not detected!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from checking the existence of the object/variable you may want to provide a "worst case" output or at least trap it into an alert so it doesn't go unnoticed.

Example of function that checks, provides alternative, and catch errors.

```
function fillForm(obj) {
  try {
    var output;
    output = (typeof obj !== 'undefined') ? obj : '';
    return (output);
  } 
  catch (err) {
    // If an error was thrown, sent it as an alert
    // to help with debugging any problems
    alert(err.toString());
    // If the obj doesn't exist or it's empty 
    // I want to fill the form with ""
    return ('');
  } // catch End
} // fillForm End
```

I created this also because the object I was passing to it could be  x  ,  x.m  , x.m[z]  and  typeof x.m[z] would fail with an error if x.m did not exist.

I hope it helps. (BTW, I am novice with JS)

Answer (score 1):

for me this worked for a DOM-object:

```
if(document.getElementsById('IDname').length != 0 ){
   alert("object exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n === Object(n)) {
   // code
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the `&&` operator.

```
key && value
```

In this case if the key returns any value that is not:

- null
- NaN
- 0
- false
- undefined
- empty string ("" or '' or ``)

it will return `key`, else it will return `value`.
In other words if the value is true (exists) it returns key else it returns value.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer. In fact, you give a way to get the right object but not how to check it

Comment: @Elikill58 so something along the lines of !value && alert("message")? would that be considered a check?

Comment: It could be, but it's not the usecase of OP. Like you can only use this with something else, you can simply have a line like `maybeObject && alert("GOT HERE");` It's not valid JS. Generally, we use this like `obj = maybeObject && defaultObj();` for example, and IMO it's not what's your explaining/we can understand with your post

Comment: That's actually a good point, I understand it now.

Answer (score -1):

set Textbox value to one frame to inline frame using div alignmnt tabbed panel.
So first of all, before set the value we need check selected tabbed panels frame available or not using following codes:

Javascript Code :

```
/////////////////////////////////////////
<script>

function set_TextID()
            {
                try
                    {
                        if(!parent.frames["entry"])
                            {
                            alert("Frame object not found");    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var setText=document.getElementById("formx").value;
                                parent.frames["entry"].document.getElementById("form_id").value=setText;
                            }
                            if(!parent.frames["education"])
                            {
                            alert("Frame object not found");    

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var setText=document.getElementById("formx").value;
                                parent.frames["education"].document.getElementById("form_id").value=setText;
                            }
                            if(!parent.frames["contact"])
                            {
                            alert("Frame object not found");    

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var setText=document.getElementById("formx").value;
                                parent.frames["contact"].document.getElementById("form_id").value=setText;
                            }

                        }catch(exception){}
                }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

zero and null are implicit pointers.  If you arn't doing arithmetic, comparing, or printing '0' to screen there is no need to actually type it.  Its implicit.  As in implied.  Typeof is also not required for the same reason.  Watch.

if(obj) console.log("exists");

I didn't see request for a not or else there for it is not included as.  As much as i love extra content which doesn't fit into the question.  Lets keep it simple.

Comment: I see _a not_ in the question: `if (!maybeObject)` - but indeed, the title asks for the opposite.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (maybeObject !== undefined)
  alert("Got here!");
```

Answer (score -4):

Think it's easiest like this

```
if(myobject_or_myvar)
    alert('it exists');
else
   alert("what the hell you'll talking about");
```

Answer (score -11):

Or, you can all start using my exclusive **exists()** method instead and be able to do things considered impossible. i.e.:

Things like: `exists("blabla")`, or even:  `exists("foreignObject.guessedProperty.guessNext.propertyNeeded")` are also possible...

Comment: And where is that method?