# Know if a DOM object is dead

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am working with a variable containing a webpage element such as a button.
However, sometimes I get the error "Can't access to a dead object" because the page containing the element has changed since the moment I saved it.

I would like to know a way to check if an element is dead or not, I tried :

```
if(element)
    alert("Do something");
```

but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: how about `if(!!element)`? this will force `element` to be truthy

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4186939/1862502

Comment: FYI to people who post answers, this is a [Firefox protection](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/09/12/what-does-cant-access-dead-object-mean/)

Comment: And to people who suggest duplicates: the question is about DOM objects, not JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copied from [How to check if element exists in the visible DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom)

```
   var elementInDocument = function(element) {
        while (element = element.parentNode) {
            if (element == document) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You can use it like:

```
if(elementInDocument(element))
    alert("Do something");
```

Comment: It's quite obvious finally, I just have to check if the element is present in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
//eval it in your mozilla-browser space

var dc = content.document;
content.document.location.reload();
setTimeout(function(){ 
  try{ 
    dc.parentNode;
  }catch(e){
    if (e.message.indexOf(' dead ')!=-1){
        alert('REALY DEAD!');
    }
} }, 1000);
```

it is a test of dead (in try..catch block) in my moz extension projects.