# Add external file to head - one for Staging and one for Production

Tags: javascript

I need to add an external javascript file to the `<head>` section of a website - one file when on the Staging server, and a different one for production.

So far I have this, but I get an error: 'return' outside of function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pathOrigin = window.location.origin;
    var headtg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        if (!headtg) {
            return;
        }
    var linktg = document.createElement('script');
        if (pathOrigin.toLowerCase().indexOf("staging.server.com") >= 0) {
            linktg.src = '/script-staging.js';
        } else {
            linktg.src = '/script-production.js';
        }
headtg.appendChild(linktg);
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Return - Specifies the value to be returned by a function.

That means the error you got from the browser is correct. Your `return`statement is not part of a function, but of the global scope. You wil either have to skip using the `return` statement and use simple variable assingment like in @Azzy's answer, or encapsulate it in a function like so:

```
function getHead() {
  var headtg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    if (typeof headtg === 'undefined') {
      return; // will break the function
    } else {
       var linktg = document.createElement('script');
       if (pathOrigin.toLowerCase().indexOf("staging.server.com") >= 0) {
         linktg.src = '/script-staging.js';
       } else {
         linktg.src = '/script-production.js';
       }
    headtg.appendChild(linktg);
    };
};
getHead(); // don't forget to initialize the function
//or you could do:
element.onload/onclick/on<whatever_event> = getHead();
```

To me it is also not clear what you want to return, unless you simply want to stop script execution; citing from MDN:

> If the expression in return [expression] is omitted, undefined is returned instead.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

NB: Check this why it is safer to use the `typeof`statement than a simple `!`mark to check if something exists: [Check if object exists in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186906/check-if-object-exists-in-javascript).

**EDIT: For a very simple use case of the return statement, you can check out [this fiddle I made](http://jsbin.com/ocAQiDA/4/edit) which is basically a counter that will output an error when it reaches 100.**

Comment: Ok, thanks. What should the entire code look like then? I still get: 'return' statement outside of function.

Comment: @Meek, that depends on what you want to return if the `head` tag is not present. Do you want to append it if it is absent? (kind of strange, since normally every HTML doc has a `head` but ok..). Do you want to output a console error?

Comment: I guess I would like the script to just stop executing although it's highly unlikely that head is not present.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the full code. In this example you only needed return to break the code, but it is most often used when assigning value to variables based on if else clauses. NB: `function getHead() ` is the same as `var getHead = function()`, that's why you have to initialize it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will continue with this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Where place this code? Are you sure that the path is correct?
Another method to add js file into head is this method:

```
    <head>
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var pathOrigin = window.location.origin;
    var path = "";
    if (pathOrigin.toLowerCase().indexOf("staging.server.com") >= 0) {
        path  = '/script-staging.js';
    } else {
        path  = '/script-production.js';
    }
    document.write( '<script type="text/javascript" src="' + path + '"><\/script>' );
   </script>
   .....
   </head>
```

Comment: With this script I get an error in IE: 
Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference

Comment: It seens that "origin" is not supported in IE. With window.location.href it works.

Comment: I get pathOrigin from your code. Here is a fix: http://tosbourn.com/2013/08/javascript/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var path = window.location.origin
var fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")

if (path == 'local'){
    fileref.setAttribute("src", 'file:///D:/JS/jquery.js')  
}
else{
   fileref.setAttribute("src", 'file:///D:/JS/jquery.js')
}
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)

//list all the js loaded dynamically
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
console.log(scripts);

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

To load script dynamically, you can try out this..

The javascript error "return statement outside of function" means you've created a code fragment that is not allowed to exist outside of a function definition.