# Object present or true/false

Tags: javascript, object, boolean-logic

How would i do the below with Javascript?

```
var object

function() {
    return {
        object: Return true if object exists or object is set to true, or false if set to false, if object doesnt exisit return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if object exists in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186906/check-if-object-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: `return !!object`

Answer (score 1):

Objects that do not exist are `undefined`. You can compare object with `undefined` to check for its existence.

Make sure to use `===` to check equality with types.

Answer (score 0):

You could use instanceof to check if its an object. Typeof would return true if the object is null, because null is technically an object!

```
var obj = {};
var obj2 = null;

alert("Is obj a true object? "+isObject(obj));
alert("Is obj2 a true object? "+isObject(obj2));

// False positive
alert("Is obj a object? "+isObjectFalsePositive(obj));
alert("Is obj2 a object? "+isObjectFalsePositive(obj2));

function isObject(inputVar) {
   return inputVar instanceof Object;
}

function isObjectFalsePositive(inputVar) {
   return typeof inputVar === 'object';
}
```

Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lt2L14b/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `undefined` and `false` to return value as `false`. If the `object` value is set to true the return flag should be `true`. Below code snippet might help you.

```js
var object;
function checkObject() {
 var returnFlag;
 if(typeof object == 'undefined' || !object) {
  returnFlag = false;
 } else if(object) {
  returnFlag = true;
 }
 return returnFlag;
}

console.log(checkObject());
```

Or you can just return `!!object`

```js
var object;
function checkObject() {
 return !!object;
}

console.log(checkObject());
```

Comment: Should be `typeof object == 'undefined'`

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far however, I was hoping for a solution in one line using shorthand, that takes into account, if object = true or false or if object is simply present its true, if not present it should be false

Comment: My 2nd solution is one liner

Comment: You can remove the assignment and check it.. this will return false. I have updated my answer for your test.

Comment: in this instance i need it to return true, thats the problem :)

Comment: what you are saying, that is impractical and impossible. Javascript will not execute at all.

Answer (score -4):

`return yourElement.length > 0;`

Comment: This will get an error if the object doesn't exist.

Comment: No it wont, try it, in JavaScript its a good way to check if some element exist or not...

Comment: tried it...  `console.log(bladibla.length)` .... Uncaught ReferenceError: bladibla is not defined... of course Barmar doesn't know what he's talking about ;) =)

Comment: I wasn't clear enough - what I meant is that yourElement is defined in jQuery as: $("#YourElementID").length > 0 (that will work)