# Why is currentParent undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

In the findParentByClassName function below, currentParent is returning undefined.  Can someone tell me why?  I think it's actually returning undefined in getSongItem, clickHandler and HTML TableRowElement as well.

This is where the problem seems to be occuring.

```
var findParentByClassName = function(element, targetClass) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.parentElement && element.parentElement.className) {    
            if (element.parentElement === null) {
                console.log("No parent found");
            } else if (element.parentElement.className !== targetClass) {
                console.log("No parent found with that class name.");
            } else if (element.parentElement !== null &&
                element.parentElement.className === targetClass) {
                var currentParent = element.parentElement;
            }

            while (currentParent.className !== targetClass && currentParent.className !==
                null) {
                currentParent = currentParent.parentElement;
            }
            //I need to know why currentParent is returning undefined
            return currentParent;
        }
    }    
};
```

There may be a problem here as well.

```
var getSongItem = function(element) {
    switch (element.className) {
        case 'album-song-button':
        case 'ion-play':
        case 'ion-pause':
            return findParentByClassName(element, 'song-item-number');
        case 'album-view-song-item':
            return element.querySelector('.song-item-number');
        case 'song-item-title':
        case 'song-item-duration':
            return findParentByClassName(element, 'album-view-song-item').querySelector('.song-item-number');
        case 'song-item-number':
            return element;
        default:
            return;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can  you include HTML at Question?

Comment: I'm not sure how to, after I've already created the original post.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You are only initializing `currentParent` to a value in case the parent of `element` has the class you are looking for. In all other cases, `currentParent` is not defined. Your `while` loop would then crash, with a [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined). You might see that in the [web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console)<sup>1</sup> when you open it.

Apart from that, your code has the issue that you check if the full value of the [`class` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) equals the class you are looking for. This would go wrong when an element has `class="foo bar"` and you want to match an element with class `foo`. A better approach is to use the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
/**
 * Return the closest ancestor of the given element that has the
 * given class, or false if no such ancestor exists.
 */
function findParentWithClass(element, className) {
  if (element === null || element.parentElement === null) {
    return false;
  }
  do {
    element = element.parentElement;
  } while (!element.classList.contains(className) &&
      element.parentElement !== null);
  if (!element.classList.contains(className)) {
    return false;
  }
  return element;
}

let el = document.getElementById('start');
console.log(findParentWithClass(el, 'bar')); // will find '.bar'
console.log(findParentWithClass(el, 'fop')); // false, as there is no '.fop'
```

```html
<div class="foo red">
  <div class="bar brown">
    <div class="baz orange">
      <div class="bor blue">
        <div id="start"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

__________
<sup>1</sup>That reference is for Firefox, but all modern browsers have a web console.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to know with only the code above but you are testing for null but not undefined. I would change the code to:

```
if (typeof element.parentElement!= "undefined") {
    console.log("parentElement is undefined");
} else if (element.parentElement.className !== targetClass) {
....
```

As per [Check if object exists in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186906/check-if-object-exists-in-javascript)

Comment: The full code for the script can be found here:  https://github.com/jar9tf/bloc-jams/blob/master/scripts/album.js  I don't necessarily want to check to see if it's undefined, but rather see why it's not defined

Comment: As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement), the `parentElement` of a node is always an element or `null`, so checking for null is enough. In fact, as `null` is defined, *your* check would fail to recognize a node without parent.